# Restrict creation of resources to a particular AWS Provider Profile in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to implement a Logic to Restrict creation of AWS Resources for a Particular AWS Profile only, so that no one can accidentally create AWS resources in a different AWS Profile.

Eg -
Only if the AWS Variables are set for the below profile will the AWS Resources be created

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "AWS_Horizontal_Dev"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}
```

If the user set's the AWS Variables for a Different Profile accidentally, then the AWS resources should not be created.

**What's the best way to achieve this logic?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add `allowed_account_ids` argument here as well to restrict to exact AWS account, assuming your AWS profiles map to AWS accounts:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "AWS_Horizontal_Dev"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  allowed_account_ids = ["${var.allowed_account_id}"]
}
```

Or you could use `forbidden_account_ids` to exclude the accounts not allowed:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "AWS_Horizontal_Dev"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  forbidden_account_ids = ["${var.excluded_account_id}"]
}
```